# Unable to include css and JS files in Liferay Portlet JSP Page

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet

I have download a Jquery Image Slider source and want to integarte with my JSP File

This is my Folder Struture

[image]

This is the way i am including them

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

I get this 404 in server console

```
20:50:04,625 WARN [404_jsp:109] /css/jquery.ui.theme.css
20:50:04,640 WARN [404_jsp:109] /css/jquery.ui.core.css
20:50:04,640 WARN [404_jsp:109] /css/jquery.ui.slider.css
20:50:04,656 WARN [404_jsp:109] /css/style.css
20:50:04,671 WARN [404_jsp:109] /js/cufon-yui.js
20:50:04,671 WARN [404_jsp:109] /js/GreyscaleBasic.font.js
20:50:04,687 WARN [404_jsp:109] /js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
```

Comment: crossreferencing to the same questions in the Liferay forums https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/13575666

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several issues:

- If I see this correctly in that thumbnail image that you posted, you have your css and js folder in WEB-INF: Nothing that's in WEB-INF can be requested by any browser, so you'll never be able to get it.
- If you create docroot/css and docroot/js, you will still get 404, because you can't find the files on /css/style.css, but in /your-portlet/css/style.css - the generic way to address it in jsps is

  ```
  < link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css"/>
  ```

Late Edit: `request` on a portlet's JSP doesn't always work, because according to the JSP specification it's a HttpServletRequest. In the portal world, this is not often relative to the current path of your portlet. Thus, I'd recommend to go with Mark's answer rather than mine: liferay-portlet.xml contains files relative to the current portlet. Since Liferay 7.0, you may use an OSGi-Component's equivalent to liferay-portlet.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the request.getContextPath() , it was valuable information .

Comment: while my solution works, Mark's solution with liferay-portlet.xml would actually be more recommended. Mine is directly to your question "How do I write this correctly" while Mark answers the unasked question "How do I solve the underlying problem elegantly"

Answer (score 13):

Put the links in `liferay-portlet.xml` and let Liferay load the css and javascript. That is the better way (e.g. if user wants put two portlets to one page).

liferay-portlet.xml:

```html
<header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
<footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

And Olaf is right, you must move the css- and js-folders (and images too) from `WEB-INF` to `docroot` folder

Comment: This is best (liferay only) solution, +1.

Comment: Ya but why the names header-portlet and footer-portlet ?? ( For your information i have 6 Portlets displayed on  page ) does this make any difference ??

Comment: 1) yes, with e.g. <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css> in liferay-portlet.xml

Comment: 2) yes. Is it different portlets, or different instance of same portlet?

Comment: +1 for the liferay-portlet.xml reference. I overread that in my answer and somehow assumed that the script and link tags go into the theme, though it nowhere said that. Reading through the crossreferenced thread on liferay.com (see my comment on the question) it becomes obvious that this should be done unless it's added to the theme.